# Action Bar Title Clickable

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want Action bar title to be made clickable.

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

here the home button and backbutton perform same intent but if we want to do different action over this that is suppose up button take to home activity and home button (title) take us to home2 activity how this can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Resources.getIdentifier` to call `View.findViewById`, then attach a `View.OnClickListener` to the `TextView` that contains the `ActionBar` title.

Here's an example:

```
final int abTitleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
findViewById(abTitleId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: i havent used any text view
title is set through actionbar ab=getactionbar();
ab.settitle("hello");

Comment: @user3181391 The title, whether you set it via `ActionBar.setTitle` or not, in the `ActionBar` is displayed using [this `TextView`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/action_bar_title_item.xml#L23).

Comment: should i copty code as it is or has to be modified that is action_bar_title has to be replaced like that please be specific

Comment: @user3181391 Leave it as is, `action_bar_title` is the id of the `TextView`.

Comment: Error: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Seems it's version-specific solution only